# Proof of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that we have three integrable random variables $x,y,z$ on a probability space $(X,\Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ such that $x$ and $z$ are independent, and $y$ and $z$ are also independent. Show that for any $A\in \sigma(y)$ and $B\in\sigma(z)$, we have
$$\int_{A\cap B}\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)\,\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}=\int_{A\cap B}x\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}.$$

My partial proof is as follows: 
$$\int_{A\cap B}\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)\,\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}=\int_X\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)
\cdot \mathbb{1}_{A\cap B}\,\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}=\int_X [\mathbb{E}(x\,|\,y)\cdot \mathbb{1}_A]\cdot \mathbb{1}_B\,\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}=\int_B\mathbb{E}(x\cdot \mathbb{1}_A\,|\,y) \,\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}=\int_X\mathbb{E}(x\cdot \mathbb{1}_A\,|\,y)\cdot\mathbb{1}_B\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A\,|\,y)\cdot \mathbb{1}_B]＝\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A\,|\,y))\cdot \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_B)=\mathbb{E}(x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A)\cdot \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_B),$$
where the third equation follows from the $\sigma(y)$-measurability of $\mathbb{1}_A$; the sixth equation follows from the independence between $\sigma(y)$ and $\sigma(z)$, since we know that $\mathbb{E}(x\cdot \mathbb{1}_A\,|\,y)$ is $\sigma(y)$-measurable; and the seventh equation is due to the Iterated Expectation Law.

But I cannot proceed. I want to show that $\mathbb{E}(x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A)\cdot \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_B)=\mathbb{E}(x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A\cdot \mathbb{1}_B)$, and after that the desired result follows. However, even we know that $x$ and $\mathbb{1}_B$ are independent, and $\mathbb{1}_A$ and $\mathbb{1}_B$ are independent, in general we do not have that $x\cdot \mathbb{1}_A$ is independent to $\mathbb{1}_B$. Is my proof above flawed, or how to proceed? Any reply and hints are highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The result does not hold and the usual counterexample applies: assume that $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli $\pm1$ random variables and that $z=xy$.

Then $x$ and $y$ are independent hence $E[x\mid y]=E[x]=0$ and the LHS is zero for every $A$ and $B$.

On the other hand, if $A=[y=1]$ and $B=[z=1]$ then $x=1$ on $A\cap B$ hence the RHS is $P[A\cap B]$ and $y$ and $z$ are independent hence $P[A\cap B]=P[A]\,P[B]=\frac14\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful example! But I am afraid it does not apply to this problem. Note that here we also assumed that $z$ and $y$ are independent, which is not satisfied in your example. But anyway, thanks for your heuristic comments!

Comment: Read better: $y$ and $z$ **ARE INDEPENDENT**. I mentioned this example because it answers your question.

Comment: I am sorry for carelessness. Thank you very much for your help. It seems that I need to try other ways to establish my result.

Comment: The result you are trying to prove is **FALSE**. Hence "to try other ways to establish" it is useless.

Comment: This is an intermediate result, which, if true, can support the terminal result I want to show. My meaning is that I need to try other ways to establish the terminal result, which is only a necessary condition for the result above. But anyway, thanks for your reminding!